# Gatsby: Clicking In-Route Anchor Element Leads to Re-Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I set up a minimal Gatsby page to test when Gatsby re-renders, and I found out that just clicking a regular in-route (hash) anchor link, causes a re-render.

Why is that? Is there any way to prevent it?

Here is an example page:

```
const SomePage = props => {
  console.log('RE-RENDERING PAGE');
  return (
    <>
      <a href="#foo">Link that should not fire re-render</a>;
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I never used Gatsby, but have you tried this? https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/462#issuecomment-251765800

Comment: Also found this comment https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/487#issuecomment-366824523

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro Those issues are both long-since addressed. ;)

Comment: I can't reproduce this locally, perhaps something else is causing page re-rendering? Would you try recreating this issue in a codesandbox? Here's your code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/1vnwklxy03

Comment: @DerekNguyen Thanks. I set up a minimal working example, based on the official hello-world bare bones starter. It exhibits the problem: https://github.com/magnusriga/gatsby . Not sure what is different here and in the codesandbox example...

Comment: oohhh I can confirm that it's rerendering -- but only in chrome. In firefox nothing rerenders

Comment: @DerekNguyen You are right! Very interesting... Google chrome really shouldn't re-render there. The reason this is a problem for me, is that I do some work at re-render, which is unnecessary when in-route links are clicked. Perhaps the overall fix, beyond stilling my curiosity, is to not do any work when rendering (other than setting up functions / handlers.

Comment: it is very interesting. To add to the confusion, the codesandbox runs fine in both chrome and firefox... I have no idea what's going on. This is an observable pattern in the official Gatsby site as well. If you visit [any gatsby tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/#advanced-tutorials), turn on the react dev tool, it'll show that re-render is triggered on every header (which is a href #) click in Chrome, but not Firefox.

Comment: So I created a barebone app with `create-react-app` & the an issue happens after adding `@reach/router`. It doesn't happen in codesandbox preview panel, but if I open the preview in its own window, it happens. Perhaps we should open an issue there

Comment: @DerekNguyen Moving to twitter chat to discuss this further? I can't seem to DM. Is it open?

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"

const SomePage = props => {
  return (
    <Link to="#foo">Link that should not fire re-render</Link>;
  );
};
```

`<Link>` will render a fully accessible anchor tag with the proper `href`.

Comment: Hi. According to the Gatsby docs, in-route anchors should *not* use Gatsby Link, but instead regular <a> tags.

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#recommendations-for-programmatic-in-app-navigation

Comment: @Magnus Despite what the docs say, they actually work fine. If you [go to this page](https://www.canvas1839.com/product/cbd-relief-oil/) and click on the “Ingredients” link, which uses a Gatsby Link component with an anchor, the internal navigation will route you the correct place.

Comment: I think there is some underlying reason for why the router should not be used for in-route navigation. I don't know reach's implementation well enough, but there should be some reason why they specify it the way they do.

Comment: @coreyward and Ram, just as a side note: Swapping it out with Link does not solve the problem. It still re-renders, just now with an extra warning message from Gatsby that we are using the Link element wrong.

Comment: @Magnus Is [this the warning](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-link/src/index.js#L127) you're getting? If so, it's because your link is path relative and not host-relative. You can fix it by linking `to="/#foo"` instead.

Comment: Hi Corey, I actually went into the source code and see that they use a regex that counts all paths that start with single slashes (not double) as local, and thus should use Gatsby Link. Adding a slash just circumvents the error message, due to how the regex is built, but doesn't change the fact that in-route navigation should be done with <a> and not <Link>. All this aside though, they question at hand is more around that extra re-render. Why does it happen when there is no need?

Answer (score 2):

React re-renders a lot. Since the entire page is wrapped in a Reach Router and you're using a non-memo functional component I'm not the slightest bit surprised you're getting a console message. I was under the impression you were trying to avoid a page reload, not prop-change-based React render.

If you'd like to prevent the re-render, you can use `React.memo`:

```
const SomePage = React.memo(() => <Link to="#foo">Text</Link>)
```

Comment: Hi Corey. Yep, I was talking about re-render, not reload of page (which the router prevents). Odd thing is, the codesandbox does not re-render, but my own code does .

Comment: @Magnus That codesandbox doesn't have a router (or anything else) listening for changes to the URL/history.

Comment: But when I use a regular html anchor, no router is involved. I do not think a router has anything to do with why my own minimal repo based on the bare bones hello-world starter re-renders, but the codesandbox does not? None of them use a router, they are just using anchor elements for in-route navigation, and thus no re-render should happen.

Comment: @Magnus Your repo uses Gatsby, which includes Reach Router out of the box. Check the React Devtools.

Comment: Thanks for your continued investigation here, Corey. Even if my basic repo uses Reach Router, and the codesandbox does not, why should that result in a normal anchor tag causing a re-render? A render should happen only when state, props or context changes. Neither of those happen when navigating in-route with a hash url, via a normal anchor tag.

Comment: FYI the codesandbox link I shared _is_ in Gatsby environment -- it's the default gatsby starter

Comment: @DerekNguyen  I didn't even know that was possible.

Comment: oh yeah, blew my mind when I first saw it too! A+ work from codesandbox team

Comment: @coreyward Just as a heads up, Derek found out that it only re-renders in Chrome. Firefox does not actually re-render. As a side-thought, Codesandbox propbably uses firefox's js engine and not chrome's v8, which is why we don't see the re-render there. See comments in OP for more info.

Comment: @Magnus Interesting. In any case, if the render is problematic you can resolve it by wrapping the component in `React.memo` as I've shown. If you get to the bottom of the distinction between Firefox and Chrome I'd love to know about it!

Comment: Super, Corey. Are you on Twitter or LinkedIn? Add me and we can stay in touch? Thanks again!

Comment: Since `location` prop is passed to any page component, it should re-render even if only hash changed.

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/

So to avoid re-rendering use `memo` for the components which don't care about hash.